# Why is XPath counting the wrong number of substrings?

Tags: python, xml, selenium, xpath, robotframework

I am trying to count the number of times a element with a partial text of `"25516.B1-"` appears on the page.

Right now I am trying this. However it returns 17 even though there are only 3 instances of the element on the page.

```
Count 3 basiskerntaken
${count}=  Get Element Count   //*[contains(.,"25516.B1-")]
Log To Console  ${count}
```

Comment: this doesn't seem like python at all, is it?

Comment: `//*[contains(.,"25516.B1-")]` includes child nodes. Try `//*[contains(text(),"25516.B1-")]`

Comment: @Trapli: Closer, but see [Why is XPath contains(text(),'substring') not working as expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69909751/290085) for a problem with that approach and [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69945660/290085) for a better way to count substrings within text nodes.

Comment: @kjhughes your answer will not work with python + selenium, since the selenium insists to return webelements only, it won't return text nodes (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20375096). It might work if the xml/html source is an lxml tree or something, which is not _that picky_

Comment: @Trapli: Selenium is a handicapped host of XPath if it has such a limitation.  Alright, well, I've updated my answer for a workaround for XPath hosts that can only evaluate XPaths that return elements.  Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by doing the following

```
${count}=  Get Element Count     //td[contains(text(),'25516.B1-')]
Should Be Equal As Integers     ${count}    3
```

This returns 3 elements and passed the test.

Thanks for all the answers!

Answer (score 3):

<sub><sup>*I will use generic XPath and XML for the benefit of future readers, but the concepts are the same and can be applied to any framework that uses XPath, including [robotframework](/questions/tagged/robotframework).  See addendum regarding selenium's limitations, however.*</sup></sub>

Counting the number of *elements* whose [***string value***](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#dt-string-value) contains a substring,

```
count(//*[contains(.,"substring")])
```

will overcount the number of occurrences of the `"substring"` due to the nesting of elements.  For example, both `e` ***and*** `r` have string values that contain `"substring"`:

```
<r>
  <e>substring</e>
</r>
```

Instead, count the number of *text nodes* that contain the substring:

```
count(//text()[contains(.,"substring")])
```

There is only one such text node in the above example.

Note that this assumes that text is not partitioned across child elements:

```
<r>
  <e><b>subs</b>tring</e>
</r>
```

### See also

- [Testing text() nodes vs string values in XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34593753/290085)
- [How to use XPath contains() for specific text?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39650007/290085)

---

### Selenium-specific Addendum

@Trapli [reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69945270/why-is-xpath-counting-the-wrong-number-of-substrings?noredirect=1#comment123648208_69945270) that "selenium insists to return webelements only, [it won't return text nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20375096/290085)", here's a work-around that will return elements that selenium can then count:

```
//*[text()[contains(.,"substring")]]
```

This returns all elements that have a text node child that contains the provided `"substring"`.  It is unfortunate that selenium is limited in how it hosts XPath — most hosts are not so restrictive.

Answer (score 0):

If you know you have elements with that partial text, I would say using FindElements method to find all occurences of that method, it returns a list of elements , you can simply call List.count ();

```
List<WebElement> elementName = driver.findElements(By.LocatorStrategy("LocatorValue"));
```

`elementname.count` is your answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Update the generic *xpath* to a bit more specific *xpath* as follows:

```
${count}=  Get Element Count   //tag_name[contains(.,"25516.B1-")]
```

More canonically:

```
${count}=  Get Element Count   //tag_name[contains(.,"25516") and contains(.,"B1-")]
```

Comment: This is good if `tag_name` is known (+1).  When unknown, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69945660/290085) for an explanation of why OP's XPath was overcounting and how to correct the problem.